# Delay in Salesforce sites changes

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, sites

I'm playing with Salesforce's "Sites" functionality today for the first time, whereby I can expose Salesforce functionality to anonymous users via VisualForce.  It's cool, but I'm seeing some weird timing behavior.   I've been trying to figure it out, but it's a mystery, so I'll ask here?

When I save my changes to my VisualForce page, I would expect to see the changes right away.  Or at least, when I do a "real" save (by hitting "Save"), versus a "Quick Save," which I assume is what happens when I'm using the developer toolbar to edit -- or actually hitting the "Quick Save" button in the main VisualForce section.

At any rate, I save it as much as I possibly can, and I'm able to see the right thing when I go to the VisualForce page itself (not using the force.com URL).  But when I go to the force.com URL, I'm seeing an old version of a page.  If it's just a matter of waiting long enough, that's one thing.  But it's acting like I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

During development, it is very helpful to add a cache="false" parameter to the apex:page tag.  This should solve the issue.

[Reference page for apex:page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm) has other optional parameters as well.